# Wipe Windows 8 and replace it with Ubuntu

Tags: installation

I have a HP laptop with pre installed Windows 8, only about 12 months old, I hate it and now something has gone wrong with it and it wont reset as it says the files are missing, I have gone over to using Chromebook now, but want to use the laptop for something, how do I remove Windows and install Ubuntu in its place? I tried to install already but it won't disable the safe boot function. I'm not all that knowledgeable, but will give it a go as not much to lose as the damn thing is unusable now.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to burn the ISO (ubuntu) to a DVD and boot from it, you may have to hit F12 or F1 some F key to get into your boot order menu to select the DVD drive but after that you're home free.

I'm not too sure what Safe boot function your talking about? What laptop model is it (HP Envy etc)

Also if I remember correctly my wifes HP automatically booted the DVD before the harddrive so you might not need to go into the menu

Answer (score 0):

Burn ISO on DVD-R or DVR-RW.

You can enter boot menu by pressing DEL key rapidly after reboot.

While installing Ubuntu, tick "erase disk and install Ubuntu".

Answer (score 0):

Go to www.ubuntu.com , download the ubuntu image you want to use, burn a DVD or create a bootable USB stick, and on startup, go to bios, change the boot settings and you should get into ubuntu from the DVD or USB. :